# How to parse code from json in android just like we pass text and images?

Tags: android, json

I am creating a question answer kind of app in android and passing data through json file but  i need how to pass a code or syntax in json file which display properly in my android app.

"Question": "what is json?",
"Answer": "Javascript Object Notation",
"Image": "json.png"
     //code or syntax

But how to pass a code here?

Comment: What do you mean by " how to pass a code here?"

Comment: you need to parse the string. Json.parse

Comment: @Piyush like we pass images ,i want to pass coding syntax here in json which shows properly in my app when passing json file

Comment: @Mayuri you mean you want right Json format for question and answer?

Comment: @Mayuri First you do some research . Check this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @Piyush yes, for code

Comment: currently i m doing like this ..  {
    "Question": "Explain json object?",
    "Answer": ["A JSON object contains key/value pairs like map. The keys are strings and the values are the JSON types. Keys and values are separated by comma. The { (curly brace) represents the json object.",
      {
        "employee": {
          "name":       "Mayuri",
          "salary":      56000,
          "married":    true
        }
      }

    ]} but it is not showing like this in my app..all code display in one line

Comment: @Mayuri What you are doing here is you are having string and object(employee) in your jsonarray which is wrong format. DO you have multiple objects under Answer json array?